# amqplib - How many consumers on a queue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp, node-amqp

Using amqplib module for Node JS and RabbitMQ,

1) is there any way to tell how many subscribers there are on a queue?

2) How can i make each queue should have one consumer key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AMQP's `basic.consume` should return the number of consumers a queue has: http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html

To have just one consumer, send a `basic.consume` with `exclusive=true`

Comment: Yes right. But this for AMQP's. We are using "amqplib"